# Ruby pick random element from select list with optgroups

Tags: ruby, watir, optgroup

i m currently trying to select a random element from a select list, i can map all the options and then pick one randomly , but the problem is the optgroup inside te selector, here is a sample of the html and my code.
HML:

```
<select class="formDY-control" name="destino" id="destino">
<option value="0" style="background-color:#eeeeee">Selecciona Lugar de

 Recogida</option>
<optgroup value="0" label="Aeropuertos">
<option value="LUX01">Luxemburg Aeropuerto</option></optgroup>
<optgroup value="0" label="Todos los Destinos">
<option value="LUX01">Luxemburg Aeropuerto</option>
<option value="LUX02">Luxemburg City Ciudad</option>
</optgroup></select>
```

And here my code

```
ciudad = browser.select_list(id: 'destino').options.map(&:value)
ciudad.shift
city = ciudad.sample
browser.select_list(id: 'destino').select(city)
```

Problem is that the code returns that the selected option (array sample) is not in the select list

Comment: What is the value of `ciudad` after the first line of your code?

Comment: is an array with the  values of the dropdown counting both optgroups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of randomly picking an option value, you can pick a random option element. Then you can use it's `select` method to select that specific option (rather than asking the select list to find the option again):

```
ciudad = browser.select_list(id: 'destino').options
ciudad.shift
city = ciudad.sample
city.select
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working with arrays, and the optgroups have a value of zero, you can do something like this

```
browser
  .select_list(id: 'destino')
  .options
  .select{ |opt| opt.value != '0' }
  .map(&:value)
```

Comment: This is a nice way of picking the random elmente , but the problem comes when i need to select this value in the dropdown as i don t know how to tell ruby in which optgroup is this value

Comment: can't you just use this? http://www.rubydoc.info/github/watir/watir-classic/Watir/SelectList#select_value-instance_method